# How to analyze/filter survey results by custome variables

Tags: surveymonkey

I have created a survey with a costume variable `department`
I am using the web collector and for each department I am deploying this survey, I have a different value in that variable.
Under `analyze results` I see no way to filter by my costume variables and I am not sure I can do so via the API too.
The questions is:
Can I somehow filter by costume variables?
How can it be done?
Or do I need to download the data and do myself (which prevents me from using SM visualization tools).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe its possible currently.

Comment: Is it in the roadmap?